# API Routes handles by web Route in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm building SPA (Single-page-application) by Laravel and React JS.

I have some API routes in `api.php` of Laravel.

And I defined this route in `web.php` of Laravel to handle web routes by React JS.

```
Route::view('{any}', 'app')->where('any', '.*');
```

But the problem is that **API routes** are handled by the above code.

What should I to do ?

I don't want to write routes in Laravel and rewrite them in React JS twice.

Comment: if you really want to do that, have you tried to adjust your `RouteServiceProvider` to load your 'web.php' file after the 'api.php' file?

Comment: by default 'web.php' file loads after 'api.php' file and i didn't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these routes

```
Route::view('/{any?}', 'app')->where('any', '^(?!api\/)[\/\w\.-]*');
```

This will exclude api routes